The lable alignment is not correct with asymptote
This is a very simple code, I just to draw a triangle with an internal parallel line as below:
settings.outformat = "pdf";
unitsize(1cm);
pair A,B,C,D,E;
A=(2,5);B=(0,0);C=(7,0);
path p=(0,2)..(7,2);
draw(A--B--C--A);
label("A",A,N);
label("B",B,W);
label("C",C,E);
D=intersectionpoint(p,A..B);
E=intersectionpoint(p,A..C);
draw(D--E);
label("D",D,W);
label("E",E,E);

point A,D,B get what I designed: North, West and West, but for point C and E, they are not at what I designed to: East. Please kindly help what I have missed?


Asymptote gets confused by the node name E vs the direction E. Using another node name works:
settings.outformat = "pdf";
unitsize(1cm);
pair A,B,C,D,F;
A=(2,5);B=(0,0);C=(7,0);
path p=(0,2)..(7,2);
draw(A--B--C--A);
label("A",A,N);
label("B",B,W);
label("C",C,E);
D=intersectionpoint(p,A..B);
F=intersectionpoint(p,A..C);
draw(D--F);
label("D",D,W);
label("E",F,E);

Otherwise, you can use RightSide instead. For label E this will overlap with the diagonal below, for this you can use a scaling factor such as 2*RightSide.
settings.outformat = "pdf";
unitsize(1cm);
pair A,B,C,D,E;
A=(2,5);B=(0,0);C=(7,0);
path p=(0,2)..(7,2);
draw(A--B--C--A);
label("A",A,N);
label("B",B,W);
label("C",C,RightSide);
D=intersectionpoint(p,A..B);
E=intersectionpoint(p,A..C);
draw(D--E);
label("D",D,W);
label("E",E,2*RightSide);


